# Syntax error with INCOLLECTION, booktitle in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, syntax

My .bib file looks like this:

```
@incollection{stal2,
  author       = {Robert Stalnaker}, 
  title        = {Assertion}
  booktitle    = {Context and Content},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
   year         = 1999a,
  pages        = {78-95},
}

@incollection{stal3,
  author       = {Robert Stalnaker}, 
  title        = {On the Representation of Context}
  booktitle    = {Context and Content},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  year         = 1999b,
  pages        = {96-114},
}

@ONLINE {stal4,
    author    = "Robert Stalnaker",
    title     = "Common Ground",
    publisher = "Linguistics and Philosophy 25",
    pages     = {701-721}
    year      = "2002",
    url       = "https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1020867916902https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780190675233.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780190675233-e-27",
}

@BOOK{stal1,
    title = {Inquiry},
    publisher = {MIT Press},
    author = {Robert Stalnacker},
    year = {1984},
    edition = {},
    }
```

but for some reason whichever I put first shows up with an error message in the booktitle line, saying

> BibTeX: syntax error: found "booktitle", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In entries `stal2` and `stal3`, there's a comma missing at the end of the `title` field. Commas are *required* as separators between fields. BibTeX is looking for a signal to terminate the `title` field, but it encounters the keyword `booktitle`, triggering a syntax error report.

Incidentally, a comma is also missing at the end of the `pages` field in entry `stal4`.

*Addendum*: A still different type of syntax error lurks in the `year` fields of entries `stal2` and `stal3`. Fields are allowed to be written without `{...}` or `" ... "` delimiters if they are purely numeric (or if they are a string variable, but that isn't applicable here). The `year` fields of the two entries in question are `year = 1999a,` and `year = 1999b,`. This mixture of numerals and letters will also trigger an error. To avoid triggering an error message, you could write `year = {1999a},` and `year = {1999b},`, respectively. However, that's not really good practice, as you'd be hard-coding the letters `a` and `b` into the `year`-related information, whether or not you cite just one or both of the publications in your document. It's much better to define a macro called `\noopsort` as follows

```
\providecommand\noopsort{#1}{}
```

and write the year fields as `year = {1999{\noopsort{a}}},` and `year = {1999{\noopsort{b}}},`, respectively. BibTeX will form the appropriate year labels automatically.